# Timer monitor generating bulk of messages from camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I am having two camel routes sending fixed messages(heartbeats) using timer:monitor. This will in turn be sent to two endpoints from the Producer processor. When the message is not consumed by the consumer then the same message is retired 3 times from the producer. After successfully consuming, the timer should send the next message. But for me, it sends all the messages that were pending in the timer monitor while the message was retried in the producer.

I have used the timer monitor route as follows in my route builder

```
for (final EndpointInfo endpointInfo : endpointInfos) {
            final String uri = SIA_ENDPOINT_PREFIX + endpointInfo.getUri();
            from("timer:monitor" + uri + "?fixedRate=true&period=" + (heartbeatInterval * 1000))
                    .routeId(endpointInfo.getHeartbeatRouteId())
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .process(new SetTimeStamp(nullMessageBuilder))
                    .setBody(constant(nullMessageBuilder))
                    .doTry()
                        .process(new EndpointInfoProcessor(endpointInfo))
                        .to(uri)
                        .process(new HealthProcessor(endpointInfo, true))
                    .doCatch(Throwable.class)
                        .process(new HealthProcessor(endpointInfo, false))
                        .end();

            uris[index++] = uri;
            routeIds[index] = endpointInfo.getHeartbeatRouteId();
        }
```

How can I discard the new bulk of messages/stop the timer from sending all the messages at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `fixedRate=false`. You can read more about what fixed rate means in the JDK documentation about Timer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long)

Comment: Thanks it works!! But I still have a problem. When the retrying message gets delivered to the endpoint, then the next message from the Timer also gets delivered. Is there a way I can callback the result of the message delivery in the route builder. That way I can restrict the message in the route.